# Paste File as Link in Visual Studio, in Same Project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS2019 (also tried VS2022).
In the solution, I have multiple projects. But in one Web project, inside a folder ABC, there are some files (ASPX). I would like to re-use the same files in another folder (XYZ).

I thought I could use Copy File from solution explorer and then **Paste as Link** in the target folder. But that do nothing. I also tried to right click on the target folder in solution explorer, **Add Existing Item**, select the file and use **Add as Link**. But that doesn't work if I am adding the link the same project.

However, if I do this (**Paste as Link** or **Add Existing file, as Link**) in different project within the same solution, that works fine.

That lead me to believe that Add as Link or Paste as Link doesn't work within the same project. Can anyone confirm that and if could suggest any workaround for that?

Thank you

[image]